# C#/WP7 binding to an object containing JSON Arrays from JsonNet?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, binding, json.net

I am trying to use Bindings with ListBoxes to display a menu which is delivered in a JSON file. The problem is that the content of the "MenuEntryTemplate" below does not get displayed if I use the code below, if I place the listboxes in the CantineTemplate directly and use {Binding Meal.Lunch} and {Binding Meal.Dinner} they do work, so I wonder why adding this extra level breaks the code.

I have the following piece of JSON (for which I cannot change the format):

```
"cantines": [
    {
        "name": "Canteen A",
        "meal": {
            "lunch": [
                {
                    "type": "soup",
                    "name": "Vegetable soup"
                },
                {
                    "type": "main",
                    "name": "Burger with fries"
                },
            ],
            "dinner": [
                {
                    "type": "main",
                    "name": "Chicken breast with rice"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I deserialize this using Json.Net, which seems to properly deserialize my object into the following data structure:

```
public class MenuModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public List<Cantines> Cantines { get; set; }
}

public class Cantines
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Meals Meal { get; set; }
}

public class Meals
{
    public List<Lunches> Lunch { get; set; }
    public List<Dinners> Dinner { get; set; }
}

public class Lunches
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Dinners
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My XAML looks as follows:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MealEntryTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="MealTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- These 2 listboxes do not show up, when I leave this MealTemplate out and
             use {Binding Meal.Lunch} in the "CantineTemplate" it does work. -->
        <ListBox 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Lunch}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MealEntryTemplate}"
            />
        <ListBox 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Dinner}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MealEntryTemplate}"
            />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="CantineTemplate">
    <ListBox
        ItemsSource="{Binding Meal}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MealTemplate}"
        />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="MenuTemplate">
    <ListBox
        ItemsSource="{Binding Cantines}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CantineTemplate}"
    />
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ListBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Meal}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MealTemplate}"
    />
```

The property `Meal` is a single `Meals` object. A listbox expects a collection of objects, that's why it isn't working. You could declare the `Meal` property as a `List<Meals>` to make it work, but I don't see the point of using a listbox if there's only one element.